# If no oxygen is present, will cut avocados stop browning?

Tags: food-chemistry, enzymes

Oxygen makes cut avocados brown, or at least it is necessary to facilitate the rapid browning reaction we see within 24 hours of cutting the avocados.

If oxygen was completely removed from the air surrounding the cut avocado, will the browning stop?

If a small fraction of oxygen remained, will the browning slow? In other words, is the rate of browning proportional to the percentage of oxygen in the surrounding air?

I never studied chemistry so my understanding comes from here:

http://www.compoundchem.com/2014/08/03/why-do-avocados-turn-brown-the-chemistry-of-avocados/

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take the [tour] and visit the [help] for any questions about the site.

Answer (score 2):

Though I'm sure that it's possible for them to brown due to substances other than oxygen, in general, yes, if you remove oxygen from the cut surfaces of an avocado, it will not turn brown, and yes, if you reduce the quantity of oxygen, browning will slow.  The same works for apples, bananas, and pretty much any other fruit that browns upon exposure to air.

It's not particularly practical for intact avocados, but one method for preventing guacamole from browning is to put plastic wrap right against the surface of the dip, preventing air contact.  Additionally, if you look at packaged guacamole, in addition to the browning resistance caused by acidity, the amount of oxygen in any given container is limited to a few small bubbles.  The oxygen in those bubbles is quickly consumed and the remaining gas does not oxidize the guacamole further.

You could conceivably test this with a vacuum chamber and keep normal slices of avocado green for a prolonged time.  You also could use a food vacuum sealer that bags and evacuates food for long term storage, though ripe avocados are delicate enough that they will probably be crushed into paste by the process.

Comment: When I used to work as a chef I've soaked avocado segments in orange juice to stop browning , it may be the ascorbic acid in the juice that does this.

Comment: Acidity of orange juice is mostly due to citric acid.